# How to implement internationalization with JHipster 4.x.x?

Tags: spring-boot, internationalization, jhipster

I've modified every file related to internationalization:

- `src/main/resources/i18n/messages_en.properties`
- `src/main/webapp/i18n/en/produto.json` (my new entity)
- Added `translate` attribute to the `span` tags which already had `jhiTranslate`

None of these changes applied the translations. I already re-ran the app, killed the process in 8080 port and even restarted the computer. The files generated within `target` folder are all using the native language, as if there were no changes made in those files, like:

In `produto.component.html`:

`<th jhiSortBy="nome"><span jhiTranslate="myApp.produto.nome" translate="myApp.produto.nome">Nome</span> <span class="fa fa-sort"></span></th>`

In `messages_en.properties`:

```
### ENTITIES
## PRODUCT
myApp.produto.nome=Name
myApp.produto.descricao=Description
myApp.produto.preco=Price
myApp.produto.dataVencimento=Due Date
```

In `produto.json`:

```
{
 "myApp": {
        "produto" : {
            "home": {
                "title": "Products",
                "createLabel": "Create a new Product",
                "createOrEditLabel": "Create or edit a Product"
            },
            "created": "A new Product is created with identifier {{ param }}",
            "updated": "A Product is updated with identifier {{ param }}",
            "deleted": "A Product is deleted with identifier {{ param }}",
            "delete": {
                "question": "Are you sure you want to delete Product {{ id }}?"
            },
            "detail": {
                "title": "Product"
            },
            "nome": "Name",
            "descricao": "Description",
            "preco": "Price",
            "dataVencimento": "Due Date"
        }
    }
}
```

**Only the default texts generated by jHipster are translated.**

Is there a solution yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right file is: `src/main/webapp/i18n/en/produto.json`

If you start you application using, `./mvnw` (backend) **and** `yarn start` (frontend), then, the change will apply automatically at `localhost:9000`

Otherwise, if you only started the backend, you need to compile the front, using `yarn webpack:build` then, refresh your browser `localhost:8080`